# how to hide modal popup when page reload succeessfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have one progress modal popup that shows progress for page reloads. I have been set it to the master page and this script injects progress modal popup when the form submit fired. this is as below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProgress() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = $('<div id="myModal" runat="server"/>');
                modal.addClass("modal");
                $('body').append(modal);
                var loading = $(".loading");
                loading.show();
                var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            }, 200);
        }
        $('form').live("submit", function () {
            ShowProgress();
        });
    </script>
```

now I have one page that directly inherited to this site master and I have put this script to terminate when page loads with success. as like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myModal = $('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
        clearTimeout(myModal.data('hideInteval'))
        var id = setTimeout(function () {
            myModal.modal('hide');
        });
        myModal.data('hideInteval', id);
    })
</script>
```

but this script not works fine and see the output as like below after page loads.
[image]

what's going wrong here please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Canceling a timeout in javascript works by calling `clearTimeout(id)` with the `id` you get as a return value from `setTimeout()`.

```
let myTimeoutId = setTimeout(....); // save the returned id in a variable
clearTimeout(myTimeoutId); // clears the timeout with corresponding id
```

Comment: which value that I can set to setTimeout

Comment: `setTimeout(your_function, delay_in_ms)`